# Object is possibly 'undefined' and Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Hi I declared this map of functions. The idea is to get an object in JSON file and filter it.
So to every key I created a filter function.

```
const filterMap: Map<
  string,
  (ticket: Ticket, filter: request) => boolean
> = new Map();
filterMap.set(
  "after",
  (ticket: Ticket, filter: request) =>
    ticket.creationTime >= parseDate(filter.date)
);
filterMap.set(
  "before",
  (ticket: Ticket, filter: request) =>
    ticket.creationTime <= parseDate(filter.date)
);
filterMap.set(
  "from",
  (ticket: Ticket, filter: request) => ticket.userEmail === filter.email
);
filterMap.set("filter", (ticket: Ticket, filter: request) =>
  ticket.content.includes(filter.filter)
);
filterMap.set("", (ticket: Ticket, filter: request) =>
  ticket.content.includes(filter.filter)
);
```

Y trying to use it in this code when I want to use it

```
 const filteredTickets = tempTicketsData.filter((ticket:Ticket) => {
      if (request.kind)
        return (
      // @ts-ignore

          filterMap.get(request.kind)(ticket, request) &&
          // @ts-ignore
          filterMap.get("filter")(ticket, request)
        );
      else {
        // @ts-ignore
        return filterMap.get("filter")(ticket, request);
      }
    });
```

The issues in the title occurs where I have commented // @ts-ignore?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of the `Map.prototype.get` function is `V | undefined` (assuming `V` is the generic type of the value being stored in the map), because if you try accessing an element by a key which does not exist in the map, then the function will return `undefined`. Due to this fact, TypeScript has no way of knowing whether your key-value pair exists in the map at compile-time, so you're getting the error because you're not checking to see whether the values are not `undefined` before trying to use them. Add a check for this and the error will go away:

```
const filteredTickets = tempTicketsData.filter((ticket:Ticket) => {
    const filter = filterMap.get("filter");
    if (request.kind)
        const kind = filterMap.get(request.kind);
        if (!kind || !filter) return false; // check for undefined value

        return (
            kind(ticket, request) &&
            filter(ticket, request)
        );

    if (!filter) return false; // check for undefined value
    return filter(ticket, request);
});
```

There's also no need for the `else` after a `return` statement. Also, you should change the `return false` after the `undefined` check to whatever you want the function to return when either of the values are `undefined`

Comment: It works!
but I have the same problem with useRef() myRef.current cam be null

Comment: @MarcosMolina can you post that as a separate question with the relevant code snippets and send me the link so this one can be closed out and we don't have a long discussion in the comments?